# The type or namespace name NHVConfiguration could not be found

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-validator

I am working on some old project which is working with some old `NHibernate.Validator`. I got a exception when I build it which says `The type or namespace name 'NHVConfiguration' could not be found`.

The code caused error shows below.

```
NHVConfiguration _configOptions = new NHVConfiguration();
```

I thought it is caused by wrong version of `NHibernate.Validator`, Currently the version I reference is 1.2.0 GA. I check all the available version of it in the `sourceforge`, didn't found the right one. It seems the version of what I need is 1.0.0. But the oldest version which can be got from sourceforge is 1.2.0. So, How Can I get this missing dll? Anyone who have this dll . please give me a link to download.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and build it yourself from the source.

This looks to be around about the 1.0 release version:

- https://github.com/darioquintana/NHibernate-Validator/tree/8bef8129c2cb23c1f20695264a02dfda0972fa94

Zip of that tree:

- https://github.com/darioquintana/NHibernate-Validator/archive/8bef8129c2cb23c1f20695264a02dfda0972fa94.zip

Failing that, why not try to update your project to use the latest version.